# ASP.NET MVC LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

When I use the query

```
var NewMatchs = (from x in entity.matches select x).LastOrDefault();
```

I get error like this

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'SocialSports.Models.match
>   LastOrDefaultmatch'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

What's wrong in my code ???

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use LastOrDefault to query EF entities, as it cannot be translated to T-SQL.

Not all the LINQ methods are supported by Linq to Entities.

**List of ALL supported / not supported methods:**

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx**

You could try

```
var NewMatchs = (from x in entity.matches select x).ToList().LastOrDefault();
```

but this will load ALL matches from the db and perform Linq to objects.

Or try sorting and call **FirstOrDefault**.

Comment: .ToList().LastOrDefault() awesome!

Comment: this way is not good. Because there can be a lot of items in db.

Comment: @ДарияПечайко - that's precisely what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

`LastOrDefault` is not supported in Linq to Entities. You can achieve the same using the following:

```
var lastmatch = (from x in entity.matches select x)
                      // Assuming you have some kind of timestamp
                     .OrderByDescending(s => s.Date) 
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

See [The query operator 'LastOrDefault' is not supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/f141bb26-2288-44f1-9b7b-5297666b87a9)